# TranslateOptions for gdal.Translate function in the GDAL Java bindings

Tags: java, gdal

I'm trying to use gdal.Translate (Java bindings)
But some options (i didn't try all) from https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html does not work

If i do this, it works :

```
Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(rasterPath);
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
vector.add("-projwin");
vector.add("116.142551771");
vector.add("40.159559805");
vector.add("116.298301771");
vector.add("40.054859805");

TranslateOptions options = new TranslateOptions(vector);
gdal.Translate(rasterCutPath, dataset, options);
```

But il I want to add (for example) a scale option like this :

```
Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(rasterPath);
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
vector.add("-scale 0 4095 0 255");
vector.add("-projwin");
vector.add("116.142551771");
vector.add("40.159559805");
vector.add("116.298301771");
vector.add("40.054859805");

TranslateOptions options = new TranslateOptions(vector);
gdal.Translate(rasterCutPath, dataset, options);
```

I've got an error
ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-scale 0 4095 0 255'

Is it normal ? Do you know how to solve it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error from my side.
Just have to separate arguments (as string values) and it works :

```
Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(rasterPath);
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
vector.add("-scale");
vector.add("0");
vector.add("4095");
vector.add("0");
vector.add("255");
vector.add("-projwin");
vector.add("116.142551771");
vector.add("40.159559805");
vector.add("116.298301771");
vector.add("40.054859805");

TranslateOptions options = new TranslateOptions(vector);
gdal.Translate(rasterCutPath, dataset, options);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).